# Disable URL for Comment Author

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

In wordpress, where single post or pages we can add **Comments**. At there I need to avoid/disable the website URL input box.

There is no way in Wp-admin Panel. So How I can Disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is Simple. Just add following code in your theme's `function.php`,

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'url_filtered');
function url_filtered($fields)
{
  if(isset($fields['url']))
   unset($fields['url']);
  return $fields;
}
```

This code fully disable that URL text input.